# How do I search with the current time in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
| rsid | rsuser |      rsintime       |      rsouttime      | rsroom |
| ---- | ------ | ------------------- | ------------------- | ------ |
|    1 | Nick S | 2014-10-14 11:17:34 | 2014-10-14 12:18:06 |      1 |
|    2 | Mike G | 2014-10-15 10:18:38 | 2014-10-15 11:19:00 |      1 |
```

I want to search with the current time against the in/out times.  So, in English, if the room is busy, echo "Busy".  If it is available, echo "Room is free until " the next in time.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("008.178.143.7","roomapp","password","roomapp");
$testschedulesql = "SELECT (NOW() > rsintime AND NOW() < rsouttime) as res_rm from raRmSchedule";
$testscheduleqry = mysqli_query($con, $testschedulesql);
$testschedule = mysqli_num_rows($testscheduleqry);
if($testschedule > 0){
    echo 'Busy';
}
else{
    echo 'Not';
}
?>
```

This always returns as true.

Comment: It's supposed to work the other way around! You have a go first, and then post what you've already tried, explaining why it didn't work...

Comment: I'm stuck on even getting started.

Comment: It got me started...thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to solve it in MySQL it could be something like this:

```
SELECT IF (NOW() > rsintime AND NOW() < rsouttime)
    THEN 'Busy'
ELSE
    THEN CONCAT('Room is free until ', 
          (SELECT rsintime 
          FROM rooms 
          WHERE rsid <> rsintime 
          ORDER BY rsintime 
          LIMIT 0, 1))
AS room_status
WHERE rsid = theIdOfTheRoom
```

This is just a guide though. I'm not sure if it works because I can't test it now and a better one could probably be written to solve this. But hopefully it can get you rolling.